# Create a way to swipe through group of items

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a list of media cards. At a time 6 cards are displayed and to view next set of media cards I need to swipe right/left. How can I do this using angular ngtouch.

This is what I have for html

```
<div class="media  people-card-media col-xs-12" ng-repeat="item in heroes">
        <div class="media-left ">
            <div class="person-photo presence" >
                <img  class="media-object list__photo img-circle" ng-src="{{item.photo}}" />

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body list__body">
            <div class="people_name_title">
                <h4 class="media-heading title">{{item.name}}</h4>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="media-right media-middle contacts-chat-call flex-it-align-top">
            <a  style="margin-right: 10px;">
               call
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
```

here is the plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/XRyEwpVNXiaejojm8lEY?p=preview

any help appreciated

Comment: you can achieve this with a carousel library, for example [angular-carousel](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel)

Comment: I tried angular touch once and wasn't too impressed. You can do this with a custom directive doing something like `angular.element(document).on('touchstart', function(){ // track start})` and something similar on the `touchend` event. You just need to track the start and end x and y coordinates, then make sure that the movement along x axis is greater then y for left and right swipes, and also check that a minimum distance and time were achieved to filter out none swipe gestures.

Comment: angular-carousel helped thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel solved my problem. You turn any ul li elements to carousel